# Como usar o include other Layout do Android?

Tags: android, xml

Olá gostaria de saber como usar o **Include Other Layout** e para que serve.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Se está se referindo a tag `<include />`, ela serve para incluir uma "sub-arvore" no local onde está declarada. Em geral é bastante utilizada quando você possui um **layout** que pode ser reaproveitado em outros **layouts** ou declarado isoladamente para uma melhor organização.

Ela possui o atributo `layout`, onde você define a referência para o layout que quer incluir.

Um exemplo seria:

**layout_principal.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <include layout="@layout/layout_secundario" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**layout_secundario.xml**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Conteudo do layout_secundario -->

</FrameLayout>
```

O resultado final, quando o layout for inflado será:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <!-- Conteudo do layout_secundario -->

    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Lembrando que, assim como qualquer outro **layout**, o `layout_secundario` precisa ter apenas um elemento raiz. Para incluir mais de um elemento, você precisa ter um `ViewGroup` (excluíndo o `ScrollView` que só pode ter um filho).

---

Uma outra tag bastante usada é a `<merge />`, que excluí a necessidade de se ter apenas um elemento raiz. Com essa tag, você pode declarar exatamente como o `layout` será incluído.

Por exemplo:

Supondo o mesmo `layout_principal`, o `layout_secundario` com o uso da tag `<merge />` seria:

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!-- Conteudo do layout_secundario -->

</merge>
```

O resultado final, quando o `layout_principal` for inflado será:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <!-- Conteudo do layout_secundario -->

</LinearLayout>
```

O resultado final acaba sendo melhor em termos de quantidade de `View's` (quanto menos `Views`, melhor). Porém você precisa ter um controle na inclusão do **layout** que usa a tag `<merge />`, porque se usada sem a devida atenção pode causar resultados não esperados.